# longtblr issue (align headers, align items in 3 columns, break text in a column)

Tags: tabularray

I'm trying to mimic the table from the image. I would like to use `longtblr` because it is a bit easier for me to understand. Please bear in mind if you give me another solution, I will try to read the package documentation, but a commented source will help me even more.

[image: longtblr issues]

##### The problems

1. As you can see in the image, I want items from columns 3--5 to be aligned.
2. I also want to align headers, but maintaining the rows on `h`
3. I want also want to break the page, because I know that `longtblr` & `longtable` will not break the line, but send the info on the larger page.
4. If you look at the source code for columns 3--5, I put an extra space for items to fall on the second line. This will make the code very long and very hard to read. Is it a better solution?

##### extra

As you can see in the source code, I visualize easier the row & columns if they are set on top of others. Also, I prefer like this because my editor will wrap the text on 72 characters. If it is not much for you, I prefer to keep it in that way.

Thanks a lot!

```
...
    \hline
    Nr. Crt.
    & Unitatea de învățare
    & Competențe specifice
    & Conținuturi
    & Nr. ore.
    & Săptămîna
    & Observații \\
    \hline
...
```

##### MWE

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,landscape]{article}
% compile with different engines
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Arial}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}%{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmonofont{Cascadia Code}%
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
\else
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgtermes} % The TeX Gyre Termes family of fonts. see https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/texgyretermes/
\fi
%---------------------------------------
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ninecolors}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}


\title{\vspace{-2cm}Longtblr în \LaTeX\ }
\author{}
\date{\vspace{-1cm}\today}

\begin{document}
% \maketitle

\NewTblrTheme{fancy}{
    \SetTblrStyle{firsthead}{font=\bfseries}
    \SetTblrStyle{head}{font=\bfseries}
    \SetTblrStyle{firstfoot}{font=\bfseries,\fontshape{itshape},fg=blue1}
    \SetTblrStyle{middlefoot}{\itshape}
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{red2}
    \DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{fancy}{Continuare în pagina următoare}
    \SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{fancy}
    \DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{fancy}{(Continuare)}
    \SetTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{fancy}
}

\begin{longtblr}[
theme = fancy,
caption = {Planificare unităților de învățare pe Semestrul I},
entry = {Planificare Sem. I},
label = {tblr:plan},
% note{a} = {It is the first footnote.},
% note{b} = {It is the second long long long long long long footnote.},
% remark{Note} = {Some general note. Some general note. Some general note.},
% remark{Source} = {Made up by myself. Made up by myself. Made up by myself.},
]{
colspec = {X[h,wd=.5cm]X[h,wd=3cm]X[h,wd=5cm]X[h,wd=5cm]X[h,wd=.5cm]X[h,wd=2cm]X[l,2cm]},
rowhead = 1, rowfoot = 1%
%        row{odd} = {gray9}, row{even} = {brown9},
%        row{1-2} = {purple7}, row{Z} = {blue7},
}
\hline
Nr. Crt.
& Unitatea de învățare
& Competențe specifice
& Conținuturi
& Nr. ore.
& Săptămîna
& Observații \\
\hline
1.
& Omul romantic
& 1.2. Identificarea elementelor specifice din structura unor tipuri textuale studiate;

1.3. Exprimarea orală sau în scris a propriilor reacții și opinii privind textele receptate;

2.1. Stabilirea unor relații între o operă literară şi contextul cultural în care a fost creată

2.3. Analiza caracteristicilor esențiale ale unor epoci culturale

3.1. Folosirea unor strategii de comunicare orală în vederea înțelegerii şi interpretării textelor studiate

3.3. Argumentarea unei opțiuni personale în confruntarea cu puncte de vedere diferite exprimate în legătură
&
\-- Prezentarea programei și a
manualului\TblrNote{a}

\-- Romantismul, curent literar și
artistic

\-- Victor Hugo, Cromwell (prefața)

\-- Byron, \enquote{Visul},
Novalis, \enquote{Imn către noapte}

\-- Victor Hugo, \enquote{Legenda secolelor}
Lermontov, \enquote{Demonul}

\-- [Studiu de caz:  Evaziunea din cotidian]

\-- [Evaluare scrisă]
& 1

1

1

1

1
& 15 sept. -- 20 sept.
&  \\ \hline
2.
& Omul modern --- individul și societatea
& 1.2. Identificarea elementelor specifice din structura unor tipuri textuale studiate;

1.3. Exprimarea orală sau în scris a propriilor reacții și opinii privind textele receptate;

2.1. Stabilirea unor relații între o operă literară şi contextul cultural în care a fost creată

2.3. Analiza caracteristicilor esențiale ale unor epoci culturale

3.1. Folosirea unor strategii de comunicare orală în vederea înțelegerii şi interpretării textelor studiate

3.3. Argumentarea unei opțiuni personale în confruntarea cu puncte de vedere diferite exprimate în legătură  %%% <-- This item is breaking the page

& Realismul, curent literar şi
artistic

Honore de Balzac, Eugenie Grandet

Charles Dickens, David Copperfield

    [Studiu de caz: Afirmarea socială]

    [Evaluare scrisă]
  & 1

  1

  1

  1
  & 26 oct. -- 27 nov.
  & \\ \hline

\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd start by placing each of the numbered items in a separate table row as in `\hline
1.
& Omul romantic
& 1.2. Identificarea elementelor specifice din structura unor tipuri textuale studiate; & \-- Romantismul, curent literar și
artistic & 1 & 15 sept. -- 20 sept.
&  \\  
&& 1.3. Exprimarea orală sau în scris a propriilor reacții și opinii privind textele receptate; & \-- Victor Hugo, Cromwell (prefața)
 & 1 & & \\ `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Any kind of long table cannot be broken inside row
  but only between rows, consequently you need to consider @leandriis comment.
- Redesign for first two items in the third column ("Unitatea de învățare") -- it is entirely unclear which "items" in this column should be aligned:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgtermes}   % The TeX Gyre Termes family of fonts. 
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
%theme = fancy,
caption = {Planificare unităților de învățare pe Semestrul I},
  label = {tblr:plan},
  entry = {Planificare Sem. I},
note{a} = {It is the first footnote.},
                ]{colspec = {@{} X[h,wd=0.5cm] X[h,wd=2.0cm] X[h,wd=5.5cm]
                                 X[h,wd=5.5cm] X[h,wd=0.5cm] c l @{}},
                  rowhead = 1, 
                  %rowfoot = 1%
        %         row{odd} = {gray9}, row{even} = {brown9},
        %         row{1-2} = {purple7}, row{Z} = {blue7},
                 }
    \toprule
Nr. Crt.
    &   Unitatea de învățare
        &   Competențe specifice
            &   Conținuturi
                &   Nr. ore.
                    &   Săptămîna
                        &   Observații  \\
    \midrule
1.  
    &   Omul romantic
        &   1.2. Identificarea elementelor specifice din structura unor tipuri textuale studiate;
            &   - Prezentarea programei și a manualului\TblrNote{a}\par
                - Romantismul, curent literar și artistic
                & 1 &   15.IX. -- 20.IX
                        &               \\
    \addlinespace 
    &   &   1.3. Exprimarea orală sau în scris a propriilor reacții și opinii privind textele receptate;
            &   - Victor Hugo, Cromwell (prefața)
                & 1 &   &               \\
    \addlinespace
    &   &   2.1. Stabilirea unor relații între o operă literară şi contextul cultural în care a fost creată
            &   - George Gordon Byron, \enquote{Visul}, Novalis, \enquote{Imn către noapte}
                & 1 &   &               \\
    \addlinespace
    &   &   2.3 Analiza caracteristicilor esențiale ale unor epoci culturale
            &   - Victor Hugo, \enquote{Legenda secolelor} Lermontov, \enquote{Demonul} 
                & 1 &   &               \\ 
    \addlinespace
    &   &   3.1. Folosirea unor strategii de comunicare orală în vederea înțelegerii şi interpretării textelor studiate
            &   - [Studiu de caz:  Evaziunea din cotidian]
                & 1 &   &               \\
    \addlinespace
    &   &   3.3. Argumentarea unei opțiuni personale în confruntarea cu puncte de vedere diferite exprimate în legătură
            &   - [Evaluare scrisă]
                & 1 &   &               \\
    \midrule
2.
    &   Omul modern -- individul și societatea
        &   1.2.  Identificarea elementelor specifice din structura unor tipuri textuale studiate;
            &   Realismul, curent literar şi artistic
                & 1 &   26.IX. -- 27.X
                        &               \\
    \addlinespace
    &   &   1.3. Exprimarea orală sau în scris a propriilor reacții și opinii privind textele receptate;
            &   Honore de Balzac, Eugenie Grandet
                & 1 &   &               \\
    \addlinespace
    &   &   2.1. Stabilirea unor relații între o operă literară şi contextul cultural în care a fost creată
            &   Charles Dickens, David Copperfield
                & 1 &   &               \\    
    \addlinespace
    &   &   2.3. Analiza caracteristicilor esențiale ale unor epoci culturale
                & 1 &   &               \\
    \addlinespace
    &   &   3.1. Folosirea unor strategii de comunicare orală în vederea înțelegerii şi interpretării textelor studiate
            &   [Studiu de caz: Afirmarea socială]
                & 1 &   &               \\
    \addlinespace
    &   &   3.3. Argumentarea unei opțiuni personale în confruntarea cu puncte de vedere diferite exprimate în legătură  
            &   & 1 &   &               \\
    \midrule
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Can you please explain the `\SetCell[r=6]{l}  1. ` ? Is this span number `6` necessary for alignment? I'm asking because if I set it to `\SetCell[r=1]{l}  1. ` I don't see any changes.

Comment: @Mafsi, you are right. In your case you can even delete all `\SetCell[r=6]{l}` since text in those cells has only one line. I will correct this part of MWE ASAP